# How to index a list of class instances with a TensorFlow tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow

Given a list of class instances, I need to index it using tf.tensor. For example:

```
Class Something(): 
     def __init__(self):  
         self.a = 1
         self.b = 2

list = [Something() for a in range(0, 10)]
index_queue = tf.train.range_input_producer(len(list))
index = index_queue.dequeue()
result = list[index]
tensor = function_that_returns_tensor(result)
with tf.Session() as sess:
     sess.run(tensor)
```

The code above gives following error: `TypeError: list indices must be integers, not Tensor`

And using `tf.gather(list, index)` gives the following error:

```
TypeError: Expected binary or unicode string, got  <__main__.Something object at 0x7f4529fae2b0>
```

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Why do you use `tf.constant(..)`? `list[2]` will work fine...

Comment: I have modified the question. So index is a tf.tensor that will have some value during execution of the graph.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is due to a core mechanic in how TensorFlow works. When you call TensorFlow methods like `tf.train.range_input_producer(len(list))` or `tf.constant` you're not actually *running* those operations. You're just adding those operations to the TensorFlow computation graph. You then have to use the `run` method of a `tf.Session` instance to run those operations and get results from them. `TypeError: list indices must be integers, not Tensor` is telling you that you're passing the reference to the tensor on the computation graph as the index, not the result returned from running the operation that produces that tensor.

For a more detailed explanation, see [this TensorFlow documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/get_started#the_computational_graph).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. Yes, I understand the overall mechanic of Tensorflow. The error I reported is what I get while running those operations in tf.Session. I have modified the question accordingly.

Comment: @UmarIqbal, In your updated code, you're still passing the reference to the tensor as the index to the list and not what is returned from running the `tf.Session`. In your code, `index` is a reference to a tensor, not an integer. To get an integer from it you need to run `index_value = sess.run(index)`. Then `list[index_value]` will work.

Comment: @UmarIqbal, But also note that there is another problem with your code, which comes from using a queue. If you make the change I stated, your code will just seem to hang. This is because the queues require a queue runner to work. More information on that [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/threading_and_queues). But your original example which used a constant (or some other non-queue generated tensor) instead of a queue should work then.

Comment: thanks for the clarification. But do we have any workaround for this? I know that tf.gather() allows to index lists using a reference to tensor, but it expects the resulting values to be of type tf.tensor. Please check the second error that I have reported.

Comment: @UmarIqbal, `tf.gather` takes in a list of tensor _references_ and tensor of indices and returns the tensor _references_ of those indices. But again, the result of the gather is not actually given to you until you run `sess.run(my_gather_op)`.